# Does Freemarker have any integration for JodaTime?

Tags: datetime, freemarker, jodatime

Are there any ways to easy format Joda DateTime objects in Freemarker?  For example with Java dates, we could use the ?string and other directives.

I know I could call toDate and get a Java Date, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to call the `toString(String pattern)` method directly from Freemarker:

`${dateTime.toString('MM-dd-yy')}`

(not tested)

Comment: so awesome, I'm new to Joda and did not see this API.  I think from my old days in Java Date world I assumed it had to be soo difficult.

Answer (score 9):

There's even a simpler way of doing this, if you don't want to splatter `toString('MM-dd-yy')` all over your templates.

Simply extend Freemarker's `DefaultObjectWrapper`, so that it understands Joda Time out of the box:

```
public class JodaAwareObjectWrapper extends DefaultObjectWrapper {

  @Override
  public TemplateModel wrap(final Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
    if (obj == null) { return super.wrap(obj); }
    if (obj instanceof LocalDate) { return new SimpleDate(((LocalDate) obj).toDate(), TemplateDateModel.DATE); }
    // add support for all desired types here...
    return super.wrap(obj);
  }
}
```

and feed this object wrapper to the FreeMarker config when you fire up your FreeMarker engine

```
Configuration config = // ...
config.setObjectWrapper(new JodaAwareObjectWrapper());
```

You can then use FreeMarkers standard date built ins, such as `${dateTime?date}` in your templates

Comment: +1, but easier to write `if (obj instanceof LocalDate) { return super.wrap(((LocalDate)obj).toDate()); }`.  Also, `if (obj == null) {...}` line is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe at this time there is any integration in Freemarker for JodaTime.  It is pretty easy to put an object in your model for formatting, i.e.

Write a class "MyCustomJodaFormatterBean", with a format(String pattern, DateTime dateTime) method.  Put an instance of  this in the root.

> root.put("joda", new
>   MyCustomJodaFormatterBean());

Then in freemarker,

```
${joda.format("MM-dd-yyy", dateTime)}
```

Answer (score 2):

During parsing of FTL files freemarker builds its internal model of objects. For example java.util.Date expressions are wrapped into **freemarker.template.SimpleDate**. If expression value of your model is of type org.joda.time.DateTime - which is unknown for freemarker, it will be wrapped by default into **freemarker.ext.beans.StringModel**, converting your DateTime to string using toString() method.

For example, assume we have in FTL expression like:

```
med.expiryDate?date <= today?date
```

Where "med.expiryDate" is of type DateTime.
"med.expiryDate" will be wrapped into freemarker.ext.beans.StringModel and after this "med.expiryDate?date" will be parsed used freemarker.template.Configuration **dateFormat**. Which can leed to exception if this dateFormat is different then default format of DateTime.toString().

To fix this you need to make Freemarker understand that DateTime is also a date, not a string. Write your custom object wraper:

```
/**
 * Wrapper to make freemarker identify org.joda.time.DateTime objects as date.
 * User: evvo
 * Date: 5/26/2016
 * Time: 18:21
 */
public class DateTimeAwareObjectWrapper extends DefaultObjectWrapper {

   @Override
   public TemplateModel wrap(Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
      if (obj instanceof DateTime) {
         return new SimpleDate(((DateTime) obj).toDate(), getDefaultDateType());
      }
      return super.wrap(obj);
   }
}
```

And set it into freemarker configuration

```
configuration.setObjectWrapper(new DateTimeAwareObjectWrapper());
```

After such change I belive **?string** suffix will also work on DateTime expression.